# Как реализовать глобальное /личное хранение файлов, загруженные пользователями?

Tags: php, логика

Допустим пользователь может загружать файлы (глобальные и личные) глобальные будут видны в поиске всем, и каждый может добавить их себе, а именно ссылку на тот файл, но так-же человек может удалить свои файлы, что делать для сохранения этого файла у других?

Comment: Если правильно сделать связи, то при удалении файла, у всех остальных он автоматически удалится. Если вам не нужно такое, то логика строго наоборот, при удалении удаляется только у одного а не у всех, файл не трогается если у него есть зависимости.

Comment: Мне не надо удалять у остальных, как тогда можно скрыть у удалившего?

Comment: для негонадо удалить его(чтоб исчез из блока его файлов, тупо хайдануть?)

Comment: Неизвестно как вы храните информацию, если в БД, то просто удаляем. что не понятно?)

Comment: Файлы хранятся в папках юзеров(автоматом создаваемые для него) а визуально это оформляется через путь к файлам которые внесены в бд

Comment: Т.е. для хозяина его локальные файлы выводятся через сканирование папки, а для других эти файлы выводятся через БД? Так сделаете чтобы в обоих случаях все было через БД.

Comment: Правильно ли я понял - пользователь может загрузить файл ТОЛЬКО к себе, а может его как-бы расшарить чтобы его могли видеть другие (сделать глобальным). При этом другие могут его добавить к себе, но если загрузивший - удалит его у себя, у других он должен остаться. Так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно обойтись без базы данных только следующим образом.

Файловые системы ext4 и прочие линуксовые поддерживают жесткие ссылки на файлы. Жесткая ссылка это указатель на место хранения файла, она не выделяет дополнительного пространства. Место на диске считается свободным когда на это место не осталось ни одной жесткой ссылки. Если пользователь удалит этот файл у себя - останутся ссылки и место не освободится пока все не удалят этот файл у себя.

А лучше сделайте базу данных. Две таблички: одна с именем файла, вторая со ссылками на него. `DROP CASCADE` и триггер на удаление через который можно удалить файл физически.